# Probability limits of Markov chains

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

> Given the following matrix for a seven state Markov chain, find $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}p^n(i, j).$
>   [image]

I know that, given a transient set $T$ and recurrent set $R$, we have $$lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}p^n(i,j) = (I - P_{T,T})^{-1} P_{T,R}$$
I'm currently getting $$lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}p^n(i, j) = \begin{pmatrix} 
.125 & .15 & .725 & 0 & 0\\
0 & .4 & .6 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$ where $j \in$ {1, 5, 4, 6, 7}.

However, I'm finding it odd that $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}p^n(i, j)$ for all $i \in$ {2, 3} and $j \in$ {6, 7}. While we cannot go from 2 or 3 to 6 or 7 in one step, surely once we get to 4 it's inevitable that we get to 6 or 7.

Is my answer incorrect, or am I potentially misunderstanding the definition?

Comment: State 7 always transitions back to state 4.

Answer (score 1):

The limiting behavior of this Markov chain, call it $\{X_n:n=0,1,2,\ldots\}$, depends on the initial state, since not all states communicate. For example, $p(1,j)=0$ for $j\notin\{1,5\}$, so $$\mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\{X_n \in \{1,5\}\mid X_0 = 1\}\right)=1.$$
Taking the substochastic matrix generated by states $1$ and $5$, we see that
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac7{10}&\frac3{10}\\\frac35&\frac25
\end{pmatrix}^n 
= \begin{pmatrix}
\frac23 + \frac13\cdot10^{-n}&&\frac13 - \frac13\cdot 10^{-n}\\\frac23-\frac23\cdot10^{-n}&&\frac13+\frac23\cdot10^{-n}
\end{pmatrix}
\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac23 &&\frac13 \\\frac23&&\frac13
\end{pmatrix},
$$
and similarly the substochastic matrix generated by states $4$, $6$, and $7$, we that
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{4}{5} \\
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)^n\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{8}{17} & \frac{5}{17} & \frac{4}{17} \\
 \frac{8}{17} & \frac{5}{17} & \frac{4}{17} \\
 \frac{8}{17} & \frac{5}{17} & \frac{4}{17} \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$
Let $\tau_{2,\{1,5\}}=\mathbb P\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{X_n\in\{1,5\}\mid X_0=2\}\right)$ and similarly define $\tau_{3,\{1,5\}}$, $\tau_{2,\{4,6,7\}}$, and $\tau_{3,\{4,6,7\}}$. That is, $\tau_{i,A}$ is the probability that starting in state $i$, the process will reach the class of states $A$. Then
\begin{align}
\tau_{2,\{1,5\}} &= \frac1{10} + \frac15\tau_{2,\{1,5\}} + \frac3{10}\tau_{3,\{1,5\}}\\
\tau_{3,\{1,5\}} &= \frac15 + \frac12\tau_{3,\{1,5\}}\\
\tau_{2,\{4,6,7\}} &= \frac25 + \frac15\tau_{2,\{4,6,7\}} + \frac3{10}\tau_{3,\{4,6,7\}}\\
\tau_{3,\{4,6,7\}} &=\frac3{10} + \frac12\tau_{3,\{4,6,7\}},
\end{align}
and solving these equations yields
$$
\tau_{2,\{1,5\}} = \frac{11}{40},\quad \tau_{3,\{1,5\}} = \frac24,\quad \tau_{2,\{4,6,7\}} = \frac{29}{40},\quad \tau_{3,\{4,6,7\}} = \frac35.
$$
Scaling rows $2$ and $3$ by the appropriate $\tau_{i,A}$ factors, we have the limiting probability matrix (conditional on the starting state, that is):
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac23 &0&0&0& \frac13&0&0\\
\frac{11}{60}&0&0&\frac{29}{85}&\frac{11}{120}&\frac{29}{136}&\frac{29}{170}\\
\frac4{15} &0&0&\frac{24}{85}& \frac2{15}&\frac{3}{17}&\frac{12}{85}\\
0&0&0&\frac{8}{17} &0& \frac{5}{17} & \frac{4}{17}\\
\frac23 &0&0&0& \frac13&0&0\\
0&0&0&\frac{8}{17} &0& \frac{5}{17} & \frac{4}{17}\\
0&0&0&\frac{8}{17} &0& \frac{5}{17} & \frac{4}{17}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$